# Remove old binary revisions from git and reduce size of git repository

Tags: git

So currently I have what seems to be a very complex problem and I need some help on how to fix it without the ability to move binary files to a CDN / dropbox etc.  When evaluating this problem please note that removing images / pdfs etc and putting them in dropbox or some other external storage is unfortunately not an option.

So the current issue is that I have a couple hundred repositories and each have a few thousand commits and each repo in general have 3 branches.  On one of my test repos if I do a du -sh of the repository it's about 13gb in size.  Where as the working directory is about 800mb in size.  So what I have tried thus far to reduce the size is the following:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/largest/files.pdf" HEAD
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all &&  git gc --aggressive --prune
git gc --prune=now --aggressive
git repack -a -d --depth=250 --window=250
```

After all the tests above the repository directory on du -sh still shows it at 13GB in size.  So my next thought is to remove all binary file history (jpg / pdf / png etc) but keep only the latest revision of the binary file.  However I'm not sure on how to accomplish that, I *could* do a
    for i in `find -name "*.pdf"`; do
        git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch $i" HEAD
    done 
for instance, but I'm not sure if thats the best way to go about things as it would probably take forever to complete all the different asset types.

The main objective here is to reduce size by only keeping 1 revision of the binary files in history so that the pack files are smaller in size, all previously deleted binaries in history could also be removed, which I'm 100% fine with but also not sure on how to do that in an automated fashion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that these files are still referenced in other branches? How many branches do you have anyway?

Comment: In general we always keep 3 branches to keep the amount of branches down to a minimum due to this exact problem.  We use the *master* branch for mainline development, master branch is then merged to a testing branch where it's evaluated for stability.  And finally the testing branch is merged into the production branch.

Comment: One exception to this is if there is a new feature to be added that will span multiple sprints for instance then an additional feature branch is created.  However that branch is eventually merged back into master branch and the branch is then deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have 3 branches, why don't you specify to work on all branches for the first `git filter-branch` command?

```bash
git filter-branch --index-filter \
"git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path/to/largest/files.pdf" -- --all
```

Then to remove the references to `refs/original` I would propose the following command:

```bash
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/original/ | \
xargs -n 1 git update-ref -d
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used these commands with some success.

```sh
git filter-branch \
  --index-filter "git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch '$1'" \
  --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all || exit

# Cleanup and reclaming space
rm -r .git/refs/original
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

[**ref**](http://raw.github.com/svnpenn/a/master/scripts/git-remove.sh)

Comment: As with my own tests this works but it also wipes the files completely .  The goal is to only remove previous versions of the binaries but keep the latest versions in tact and fully remove only deleted files in the final