# How can I reduce the size of the '.git' folder with a huge history of commits?

Tags: git, github

We are working in a group and committing data daily in large numbers due to which *.git* folder is becoming very heavy in size. And while performing the **pull** command on our system, it takes a lot of time due to heavy size of the *.git* folder. How can we clean or reduce the size of this Git repository?

Comment: https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/handle-big-repositories-git should be helpful

Comment: Tried [garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size)?

Comment: Step number one is to figure out if you really need “version control” or perhaps “synchronization” or “keep last 100 changes”. Git only directly implements the first as far as the repo itself is concerned, but you can get “last 100 changes” with a shallow clone.

Comment: Related: *[Make Git consume less disk space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398919/)* and *[Reduce Git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116778/reduce-git-repository-size/2116892#2116892)*

Answer (score 1):

If most of the file size is taken up by old commits in the `.git` folder, rather than current files, you can rebase a specific recent commit as the root, keeping all files and commits from that point on but getting rid of older history.

Make sure to back everything up first!

Quoting this answer (*[How do I reduce the size of a bloated Git repo by non-interactively squashing all commits except for the most recent ones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153548/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-bloated-git-repo-by-non-interactively-squashing-al/24153726#24153726)*):

> One way to do this is here, assuming your current work is called
> `branchname`.  I like to use a temp tag whenever I do a large rebase
> to double-check that there were no changes and to mark a point I can
> `reset` back to if something goes wrong (not sure if this is standard
> procedure or not but it works for me):
>
> ```bash
> git tag temp
>
> git checkout 10004
> git checkout --orphan new_root
> git commit -m "set new root 10004"
>
> git rebase --onto new_root 10004 branchname
>
> git diff temp   # verification that it worked with no changes
> git tag -d temp
> git branch -D new_root
> ```
>
> To get rid of the old branch you'll need to delete all tags and branch
> tags on it; then
>
> ```
> git prune
> git gc
> ```
>
> will clean it from your repo.
>
> Note that you'll temporarily have two copies of everything, until you
> have `gc`'d, but that is unavoidable; even if you do a standard squash
> and rebase you still have two copies of everything until the rebase
> finishes.

Comment: This procedure may have made sense at one time, but now it's just a manual way to imitate "shallowing" of a repo. A true shallow repo (e.g. once created by using the `depth` parameter to `clone`) is better, in fact, because it preserves commit ID's (which can be useful for many reasons, especially if you keep an archive of the original history).  Also, as an aside, this business about having "two copies of everything" after a rebase is incorrect; that's not how git stores things.

Answer (score 0):

You need to determine if there is something inherently big in your repository—like too many big binary files—or if a garbage collection will fix it.

Do a garbage collection, and see how big your repository is.

If that doesn't fix it, look at the [Atlassian link](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/handle-big-repositories-git) that [sauerburger provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45864180/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-the-git-folder-with-a-huge-history-of-commits#comment78686895_45864180), or do some other googling based on what you find there.

(The details of these steps are intentionally left as an exercise for the user.)